# Display custom post meta data to wordpress menu item

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my first post so first of all : hello everybody, glad to be a part of the community.
Secondly please escuse-me in advance for all the English mistakes, i'm french ...

Now this is the problem i have with Wordpress as i'm not a good developer for now :

I've created a custom post type based on the page model named 'Projects' for a more friendly display in the admin :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Projects', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Menu Projects' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art'
    ));
}
```

Then i've add some custom fields i need :

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpc_champs_personnalises_defaut');

function wpc_champs_personnalises_defaut($post_id){
if( $_GET['post_type'] = 'Projects' ){
    add_post_meta(1, 'company', '', true);
    add_post_meta(2, 'année', '', true);
}
return true;
};
```

And now what I want is to display those post meta values in my menu items , right next to the name of the page !

I've tried different things unsucessfully, so if a Wordpress master could help me, that would be great ! Thanks in advance , have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the post meta, you should supply the $post_id as the first argument.

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'company', 'value here' );
```

and when you want to the post meta you can use get_post_meta function

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, 'company', true );
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for responding, i can make this function works and get one particular meta if i know the post but i still don't know how to display them automatically right into the menu structure according to the post they are associated with... I'm affraid i'll probably have to work on a foreach...
One other thing - Do you know where are those meta stocked in the database?

Comment: i'm not sure which menu are you want to show the post. Is it on frontend site? If yes please read about The_Loop in WordPress (http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). And post meta is saved in wp_postmeta table in database.

Comment: Yes, I want this for a front end menu :
    register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'julie_theme' ),
  'secondary' => __( 'Projects Menu', 'julie_theme' ),
 ) );
the secondary one, i'll check the loop, thanks for the advices

Comment: I found this related question that might useful for you. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94787/get-page-ids-from-nav-items

Comment: Yes thanks Ivan, this exemple was helpfull ! I'll post an answer of what I did, may it can help somebody else .

Answer (score 0):

This is finaly how a manage to display those metas from custom fields next to each menu item.
In my exemple Company and Year :

```
/* DISPLAY CUSTOM MENU */
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'secondary'
    ) );
```

Get the menu and the items in arrays

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('Projects Menu');
    var_dump($menu);

    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id);
    var_dump($items);
```

Get all the meta in 1 array, then 1 array for each meta

```
/* GET IDs-COMPANIES-YEAR OF EACH ITEM*/
foreach ( (array) $items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $id = $menu_item->object_id;

    $meta_id = $menu_item->ID;

    $meta_company = get_post_meta( $id, 'company', true );

    $meta_year = get_post_meta( $id, 'année', true );

    $meta_array[] = array($meta_id, $meta_company, $meta_year);
}
var_dump($meta_array);

/* GET THE IDs OF THE ITEM */
foreach ($meta_array as $key => $value) {
    $meta_array_id[] = $meta_array[$key][0];
}
var_dump($meta_array_id);

/* GET THE COMPANIES NAMES OF THE ITEM */
foreach ($meta_array as $key => $value) {
    $meta_array_company[] = $meta_array[$key][1];
}
var_dump($meta_array_company);

/* GET THE YEARS OF THE ITEM */
foreach ($meta_array as $key => $value) {
    $meta_array_year[] = $meta_array[$key][2];
}
var_dump($meta_array_year);

}
```

Then convert to javascript arrays to display:

```
/* GET STRINGIFY IDs IN A JS ARRAY*/
        var js_meta_array_id = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $meta_array_id).'"' ?>];
        console.log(js_meta_array_id);
        console.log(js_meta_array_id[0]);

        /* GET COMPANIES NAMES IN A JS ARRAY*/
        var js_meta_array_company = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $meta_array_company).'"'   ?>];
        console.log(js_meta_array_company);

        /* GET YEARS IN A JS ARRAY*/
        var js_meta_array_year = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $meta_array_year).'"' ?>];
        console.log(js_meta_array_year);
```

Target the items

```
/* GET MENU PROJECTS MENU */
        var menu_project_id = $('#menu-projects-menu');
        console.log(menu_project_id);

        /*GET MENU PROJECTS ITEMS ID*/
        var item = menu_project_id.children('.menu-item');
        console.log(item);
```

And Finally add the meta to items :

```
var length = item.length,
        element = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = item[i];
            var item_id = (element.id);

            $( "#"+item_id ).append( "<span class='company'>" +js_meta_array_company[i]+ "</span><span class='year'>" +js_meta_array_year[i]+ "</span>" );
        }
```

This is maybe quite heavy but it works fine for me !